# Opposite of Maybe data type

Tags: haskell

So the `Maybe` data type is defined like this:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

What would you call the data type that's conceptually opposite to `Maybe`:

```
data <Type> = Okay | Error String
```

That is, a type that declares the computation successful or holds some error produced by the computation.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that this data type is equivalent to `Either String ()`, where `Okay = Right ()` and `Error = Left`.

Comment: Yup, I know that. I'm interested in a more descriptive name though.

Comment: I think that `Either` is such a well known type, that any Haskell programmer looking at a type of `Either String ()` would understand its purpose immediately. Using a different name would probably only make the code more difficult to follow.

Comment: @HaithamGad Then just give it a type alias.  It's standard to use `Either` to indicate possible failure with an error value.  If you had `type ErrorMsg = String` then `foo ::  a -> Either ErrorMsg b`, every Haskeller would immediately understand the purpose of `foo`.

Comment: Regardless how it's implemented, I'm just interested in a good name for that type. `Either` could be idiomatic, but the name is not ideal here.

Answer (score 8):

I refute the premise that this type is in a meaningful sense “opposite” to `Maybe`. I also don't agree that `Either` should generally be understood as an error-signalling type – that's just quite a natural way of using it, due to the way its monad instance works.

Both `Maybe` and `Either` know nothing about errors / failure – they're just implementations of the abstract concept of a sum type (in the case of `Maybe` a sum with the unit type).

IMO, you should just use `Maybe String` for this purpose, or if you like it explicit:

```
type ErrorMsg = String
type PossibleError = Maybe ErrorMsg
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `Either String ()`, using the common convention that an `Either` is used to signal errors with information in the `Left` and the success value in the `Right`. If you don't actually have a success value, use the unit type `()`.

Of course, that still needs to be wrapped in some monad, because in Haskell a pure function without a result is not useful. If the purpose of your function is just to check the validity of some data, then it's not an error to return the error string, and I'd go back to using `Maybe`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<Type>` is equivalent to `Either String ()`, so you could just have

```
type CanError = Either String ()

isOkay :: CanError -> Bool
isOkay = Data.Either.isRight

isError :: CanError -> Bool
isError = Data.Either.isLeft

getErrorMsg :: CanError -> Maybe String
getErrorMsg (Left msg) = Just msg
getErrorMsg _ = Nothing
```

You can use `Either String` as a Monad/Applicative/Functor, but not `CanError` since it has kind `*`, not `* -> *` as required by each of those typeclasses.  I would recommend just using `Either String` as is since you get the extra power of Monad/Applicative/Functor/etc., and when you need the equivalent of `CanError` just have the return type be `Either String ()` in-line.

Answer (score 2):

Another example for what perhaps is the general idea behind your question, that success is the exceptional case and failure is the normal case, is `EitherR` as provided in the [errors package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Data-EitherR.html#t:EitherR) whose `Monad` instance is suggestively referred to as the "success" monad. As the name suggests there's no magic here, it's just a `newtype` with `Monad` instances swapped around. The interpretation, however, is interesting.

You can program in a world where success falls through while errors are kept around. As the package documentation indicates, this comes in handy when dealing with stacks of exception handlers.